# Phantomjs/CasperJs not rendering page so i can extract links

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs with phantomjs on php to render webpage before extracting any links , in this way usually all links that are created by javascript are coming out and i can see them but not on this website:
centralcanadaclassics(.)com

here is JS for CasperJS that i am using:

```
var xpath = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    webSecurityEnabled: false
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    colorizerType: 'Dummy'
});

casper.userAgent('casper');
casper.start().then(function() {
    this.open('http://www.centralcanadaclassics.com', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/html'
        }
     });
});
casper.then(function () {
    this.echo('[CURRENT_URL]' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.echo('[CURRENT_TITLE]' + this.getTitle());
    this.echo('[CURRENT_PAGE_CONTENT]' + 
    this.getPageContent().replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), ''));
    this.echo('[CURRENT_HTML]' + this.getHTML().replace(new RegExp('\r? \n','g'), ''));
    this.echo('[CURRENT_HEADERS]' +  JSON.stringify(this.currentResponse.headers));
    this.echo('[CURRENT_STATUS]' + this.currentResponse.status);
    this.echo('[CURRENT_STATUS_TEXT]' + this.currentResponse.statusText);
    this.echo('[CURRENT_COOKIES]' + JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies));
});
casper.run();
```

So at the end all content stays the same , doesnt render that page.
Please explain why ?

Comment: So, you want to extract all the links on that page? And you are wondering why you can't see the links in casperjs output, but you can see it in normal browser?

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS is asynchronous.  You're dumping your data right as it's opening the page, so I'm going to go on a limb here and say that it's doing exactly what you are telling it do,  open a page, and while it's rendering that page (meaning before it completes) try to use the content.

If there is JS rendering (dynamic) of the page content, you'll need to implement a wait, either a hard-coded delay (very brittle) or identify a commonly rendered element and tell CapserJS to wait until it sees it, before doing any sort of link hunting.

Here is an example of what you might do using your own link parsing look which I'm going to call  'getLinks()';

```
// open the page
casper.thenOpen(url).then(function() {
    if (this.exists('#some-id')) {
        this.getLinks();   // this is your link hunting function
    }
});
```

Or something like this

```
casper.wait(1000, function() {
    casper.then(function() {
        this.getLinks();   // this is your link hunting function
    });
});
```

I think you're trying to use the content before it's rendered.